# Please send me some faucet ETH of ropsten network

Tags: mist, testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ropsten, faucets

My  adress of metamask wallet is `0x7E279990b12980d37C87abF402f1356b1Dc6F05f`

Please soem one can provide me some ETH faucets to test my application?

Comment: Please mention the testnet you would like to use. You can easily get ETH using the faucet on rinkeby testnet. https://www.rinkeby.io/

Comment: i am using ropsten testnet  and how can i get rinkeby testnet faucet

Comment: I've suggested a duplicate for this question - faucet details are contained in the answers. The Ropsten faucet has had a few problems recently.

Comment: surely this is more suited for [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/)

Comment: Ropsten has been deprecated, Goerli is now the only Ethereum supported testnet. If you need any Goerli - https://goerlifaucet.com, you can get Goerli testETH every day reliably

Answer (score 5):

Little, free and fast tutorial for obtain ether by faucet in metamask

First, click on buy button:

[image: firs picture]

Second, click on "Ropsten test faucet" or other Testnet faucet:

[image: second picture]

Finally, here you can send some ether to your account:

[image: third picture]

Comment: my addres is not detected in https://faucet.metamask.io/ , what is the problem i don't understand

Comment: So make a question with your problem man... and someone explain you why is not detected your address. Where you create this address?